# Could not disable back button in storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios5.1

Scene is with Storyboard, here is the Structure 
UINavigationController > NavigationController > UITabBarController > UIViewController

I am trying below options to hide back button over to last UIViewController but it doesn't work.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=nil;
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem=nil;
self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=nil;
self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem=nil;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
self.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
```

Can anyone help or let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: do you need the navigation bar? you could try hiding it with this  [[self navigationController]setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

Comment: Thanks gg13, I figured out the solution and the cause due to which I suck. I added it as answer to my question.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I got my answer.

```
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
```

As I am using UITabBarController, I should do this and using this, actually solved my issue.

Comment: Jeez, this took me way too long to find.